# Unexplained line break

Tags: bash

I'm very sorry if someone already have ask this question or something near it, but I did not found anything close to it, but may be it's because of my weakness in coding.

I have bash this script:

```
...
...
## Read n line in vmlist
VMTORESTORE=$(sed -n "$yn p" ./vmlist)
## Replace " " between names by "\ "
VMTORESTORE="$(echo "$VMTORESTORE" | sed 's/ /\\ /g'  )"
## Test variable
echo $VMTORESTORE
## Run Command
ls -1 /vmfs/volumes/BACKUP_SAN/$VMTORESTORE | sed 's/ /\\ /g'
```

This is the result:

> Save\ Camera
>
> ls: /vmfs/volumes/BACKUP_SAN/Save: No such file or
>   directory
>
> Camera:

I don't understand why the echo gave the good result whereas the command insert a line break between Save\ and Camera.

thanks by advance for your help.

Proc

Comment: Does the error not say `ls: /vmfs/volumes/BACKUP_SAN/Save\: No such file or directory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all, I did not expect a solution that easy.
You were right, the double quotes were needed.

But in my cas this was not enough.
The path to the searched folder was:

"/vmfs/volume/BACKUP_SAN/Save Camera/"

but usually in Linux to reach this kind of folder I need to put \ before spaces like that:

"/vmfs/volume/BACKUP_SAN/Save\ Camera/"

That's why I replaced in my script all " " with "\ "

But is seems in a bash script this is not needed so this works like a charm:

```
...
...
## Read n line in vmlist
VMTORESTORE=$(sed -n "$yn p" ./vmlist)
## Run Command
ls -1 "/vmfs/volumes/BACKUP_SAN/$VMTORESTORE"
```

I searched the complication whereas it was this simple.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

it is a good idea to quote the variables as in:

```
ls -1 "/vmfs/volumes/BACKUP_SAN/$VMTORESTORE"
```

Take this as a good practice and update the script wherever needed.

Comment: This still won't work since there is a backslash in the filename.

Comment: Yes, but doing this is the correct solution *instead* of adding backslashes in an attempt to escape the space.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `\` is an escape character in bash. So shouldnt your path consists of `/` rather than `\` to define the location `save/camera`. Also globbing happens when you are using commands without `" "` so use the address in `" "`.